# Java Error: no instance(s) of type variable(s) C, T exist so that ? extends SubComponent<T> can be converted to C

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have this quite complex class structure:

```java
public interface SubComponent<T> {...}

public interface Component<T, C extends SubComponent<T>> {...}

public class Control<T, I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> {...}
```

Then I have two classes that will hold the current state of the Control and of each Component, like this:

```java
public class ControlState<T, I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> {
    // The state keeps a reference to the Control,
    // and a map that holds all the states for each component
    private final Control<T, I> control;
    private final Map<Integer, ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> components = new TreeMap<>();

    // Has a method to add new components
    public void addComponent(int index) {
        // Here I have error on the control parameter
        ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>> state = new ComponentState<>(control, index);
        ...
    }
}

public class ComponentState<T, C extends SubComponent<T>> {
    // The component state also has a reference to the Control
    // and the index to retrieve the Component from a List in the Control
    private final Control<T, ? extends Component<T, C>> control;
    private final int index;

    public ComponentState(Control<T, ? extends Component<T, C>> control, int index) {
        this.control = control;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

In the `addComponent(int index)` method the IDE says:
Required type: `Control<T, ? extends Component<T, C>>`
Provided: `Control<T, I>`
But, since I is: `I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>` I don't understand where the issue is, types should be compatible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In very rough terms, suppose you had another class `J` which also extended  `SubComponent<T>`, but is neither a subclass nor a superclass of `I`.  You'd expect to be able to use an object of type `J` with `state`, because `state` is of type `ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>`.  So the compiler won't let you use `state` to an object that you can only use with an `I`, but not a `J`.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than that, actually.  In context, we _have_ a type `I` known to be of type `Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>`.  Let's call that `?` `X`.  The OP is trying to create a `ComponentState<T, X>`.  There isn't a separate `J` being introduced anywhere; `J` is supposed to be inferred by the compiler to be equal to `I`, and it isn't.  (It's not determined by the caller at any point.)

Comment: In my debugging, I've narrowed this down to: `
  private static <T, I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>> implicitC(Control<T, I> control, int index) {
    return explicitC(control, index);
  }

  private static <T, C extends SubComponent<T>, I extends Component<T, C>> ComponentState<T, C> explicitC(Control<T, I> control, int index) {
    return new ComponentState<>(control, index);
  }`.  That's long, and I don't have a shorter repro, but (continued next comment)

Comment: A `C` that fulfills the constraints of `explicitC` exists; it's uniquely determined by `I`; it ought to be inferrable by `implicitC` -- but that block of code does not compile; it fails to infer C.

Comment: I've been nerd-sniped by this for way too long, but here's a much smaller repro of the same phenomenon: `static <L extends List<?>> void foo(L list) { bar(list); }  static <L extends List<T>, T> void bar(L list) {}`

Comment: I hope this is an academic discussion here. Combining a three-layer inheritance with multi-parameter generics will result in an unreadable and unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I decided to simplify the model by removing the `I` information from the `Control` class.

As a result, the structure looks like this:

```java
public interface SubComponent<T> {...}

public interface Component<T, C extends SubComponent<T>> {...}

public class Control<T> {
    private final List<? extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> components;
}

public class ControlState<T> {
    private final Control<T> control;
    private final Map<Integer, ComponentState<T>> components = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addComponent(int index) {
        ComponentState<T> state = new ComponentState<>(control, index);
        ...
    }
}

public class ComponentState<T> {
    private final Control<T> control;
    private Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>> component;
    private int index;
    private final Map<Integer, ? extends SubComponent<T>> subComponents = new TreeMap<>();

    public ComponentState(Control<T> control, int index) {
        this.control = control;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

That said, I would have preferred to keep that information, but I think I'm in a lucky position, meaning that as long as I tell the user that the components I need must be implementations of these two interfaces, internally I have all the APIs I need (exposed by the interfaces) to make the system work as intended

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should resolve your objective either properly or improperly. Thus, here is my idea.

In the `addComponent()` method of the `ControlState` class, you are trying to instantiate the `ComponentState` class. Now, while doing so, you can omit the **Type Argument**.
Here, the memory allocation will happen like an object of the `ComponentState` class without a type argument, i.e. non-generic type, however, the actual object will still be referred to as generic typed.

Moreover, your control object was also not instantiated (either to null or properly)

```
public class ControlState<T, I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> {
    // The state keeps a reference to the Control,
    // and a map that holds all the states for each component
    private final Control<T, I> control = null;
    private final Map<Integer, ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> components = new TreeMap<Integer, ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>>();

    // Has a method to add new components
    public void addComponent(int index) {
        // Here I have error on the control parameter
        ComponentState<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>> state = new ComponentState(control, index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot unify the wildcards of the `ComponentState.control` field and the `ComponentState` constructor, thus the type error.

You can fix this by materializing the type the wildcard stands for to match what `I` stands for in the `ControlState.state` field:

```
public class ComponentState<T, I extends Component<T, ? extends SubComponent<T>>> {
    private final Control<T, I> control;
    private final int index;

    public ComponentState(Control<T, I> control, int index) {
        this.control = control;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

You have to adjust the type of the `components` map accordingly

```
private Map<Integer, ComponentState<T, I>> components = new TreeMap<>();
```

and now you can implement `ControlState.addComponent` as

```
public void addComponent(int index) {
    ComponentState<T, I> state = new ComponentState<>(control, index);
    components.put(index, state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mention, that `C extends SubComponent<T>` is not the same as `? extends SubComponent<T>`. You have to use one of them.

```java
public class ControlState<T, C extends SubComponent<T>, I extends Component<T, C>> {

    private final Control<T, C, I> control;
    private final Map<Integer, ComponentState<T, C>> components = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addComponent(int index) {
        ComponentState<T, C> state = new ComponentState<>(control, index);
    }
}

public class ComponentState<T, C extends SubComponent<T>> {

    private final Control<T, C, ?> control;
    private final int index;

    public ComponentState(Control<T, C, ?> control, int index) {
        this.control = control;
        this.index = index;
    }
}

public interface SubComponent<T> {}
public interface Component<T, C extends SubComponent<T>> {}
public class Control<T, C extends SubComponent<T>, I extends Component<T, C>> {}
```